# Custom Designer changes the display of my components on the Design Surface

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, design-surface

> NB: I put the C# tag to get more visibility to this question, as an
>   answer in C# in fine to me, I will be able to translate it into VB
>   .NET. The problem I face is with the concept in the .NET Framework.

I am currently writing a graphic designer so that users can add my own set of customized components into a design surface, arrange them as they wish and then save it into a text file.

For most part it is working OK, but I have tried to use a custom Designer in order to hide some properties I don't want to show to the users :

```vb
Public Class MyDesigner
    Inherits ComponentDesigner

    Public Overrides Sub Initialize(component As IComponent)
        MyBase.Initialize(component)
    End Sub

    'These are the properties I will hide
    ' (real list is way longer)
    Private _hiddenPropertyList As String() = { _
        "AccessibleRole", _
        "AccessibleDescription", _
        "AccessibleName", _
        }

    Protected Overrides Sub PreFilterProperties(properties As IDictionary)
        MyBase.PreFilterProperties(properties)
        For Each PropName As String In _hiddenPropertyList
            If properties.Contains(PropName) Then
                'We hide the properties that are in the list
                properties.Remove(PropName) 
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

So this is not really complicated. To activate my designer, I must set it as attribute in my component class definition :

```vb
<Designer(GetType(MyDesigner))>
Public Class MyLabel
    Inherits Label

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So this is not really complicated either.

**The Problem**

The problem is, when a new `MyLabel` is created on the design surface and I have set the `DesignerAttribute`, it is displayed below the surface, as the picture :

[image: Custom Component wrongly displayed]

And here is the result when I remove the `DesignAttribute` :

[image: Custom Component correctly displayed]

Which is what I actually want to display.

**My Question**

What am I missing here in order to make this work ?

Comment: Hmmh, seems strange. For some reason your label is added as a component instead of an actual control when you apply the designer attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is a Control rather than Component. Thus you should use the [System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner(v=vs.110).aspx) as a base class that extends the design mode behavior of a [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx).